# Unfortunately Google play services has stopped

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am working on an application that requires the ability to share content to Google+ and deeplink back to my application. I used `PlusShare.Builder` to build my shareIntent and so far everything works perfectly.

However, i have issues when i want to share with my organizations co-operate Google account. Yes the account is an extension of gmail, and yes i have a Google+ account tied to the account and i can use is as if it were a normal Google account (except for some limitations thanks to our handy IT staffs). Every time i try to share with this account i a messages saying Google play services not working and stuff, and when i read through my log-cat i don't seen any error messages related to my app.

My question is does this happen as a result of my organizations over zealous IT staffs messing up something, or is it from the Google Play services API. What ever the case my be, what would your recommendation be?

Do i look for a way to exclude cooperate accounts from account picker and if yes how do i go about this or is there something wrong with the way i build my shareIntent.